# Direct proving "Convergence in measure implies L1 convergence"

Tags: real-analysis

Basically I am trying to prove the dominated convergence theorem with the pointwise convergence replaced by convergence in measure.
i.e if $f_n$ are measurable functions with $|f_k|\le g$ and $f_k$ converges pointwisely to $f$, then $\int |f_n-f|\to0$.

I know the proof by contradiction, I am trying to prove the result directly, since it feels possible and not complicated. But at some point I got stuck, I am here to seek for suggestions. Below is my simple observation:

First, by convergence in measure, we have $f_{n_k}\to f a.e$ and therefore we have $|f|\le|g|$

$\forall p, \epsilon>0$, $E_{p,k}=\{x:|f_k(x)-f(x)|\ge p\}$, so for large $k$, we have $\mu(E_{p,k})<\epsilon$.

Now:

$\int|f_k-f|=\int_{E_{p,k}}|f_k-f|+\int_{E_{p,k}^c}|f_k-f|\le\int_{E_{p,k}}2g+\int_{E_{p,k}^c}p$.

Since $\int g$ is absolute continuous, we can pick some large $k$, so $\int_{E_{p,k}}2g$ is very small, but the trouble is $\int_{E_{p,k}^c}p$ which is easily infinite. I am wondering is there any nice bound for $\int_{E_{p,k}^c}|f_k-f|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last term in your inequality by $\int \min \{p,g\}$. Note that $\int_{g\leq p} g \to 0$ as $p \to 0$ since $\{x:g(x)\leq p\} \cap \{x: g(x) \neq 0\}$ decreases to empty set.